# How would you use the while statement to find the square root using the while loop

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I have to write a program that will find a square root using the `while` loop. I was given this `new_guess = (old_guess + (n / old_guess)) / 2.0`; but I dont fully understand what to do with it, this is what I have:

```
int main(void)
{
    double n, x, new_guess, old_guess, value;
    printf("Enter a number:");
    scanf("%lf", &n);

    x = 1.00000;

    while (new_guess >= n) {
        new_guess = (old_guess + (n / old_guess)) / 2.0;
        printf("%10.5lf\n", fabs(new_guess));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`x` is the initial guess. Im really lost on how to do it. This is C also. I know its really wrong but I really dont understand how to make it start because when I enter a number it just stop right away.

Comment: but most of your variables are not initialized or used???

Comment: I know and thats why im lost. should i make old_guess = n/2?

Comment: After scanf, put this: `old_guess = n/2;`

Comment: I don't see where `x = 1.00000 ;` is *used*, suggesting that this might not be quite a minimal example.

Comment: `while (new_guess >= n)` makes no sense as the loop condition.

Comment: I know it doesnt but i dont know what to put, i was thinking something like     while(1e-6 < x - new_guess) but im not so sure

Answer (score 1):

Your program has undefined behavior because both `new_guess` and `old_guess` are uninitialized when you enter the loop.

The condition is also incorrect: you should stop when `new_guess == old_guess` or after a reasonable maximum number of iterations.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double n, x;
    int i;

    printf("Enter numbers:");
    while (scanf("%lf", &n) == 1 && n >= 0.0) {
        x = 1.0;

        /* Using a while loop as per the assignment...
         * a for loop would be much less error prone.
         */
        i = 0;
        while (i < 1024) {
            double new_guess = (x + (n / x)) / 2.0;
            if (new_guess == x)
                break;
            x = new_guess;
            i++;
        }
        printf("%g: %.17g, %d iterations, diff=%.17g\n",
               n, x, i, sqrt(n) - x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Given the start value, the number of iterations grows with the size of `n`, exceeding 500 for very large numbers, but usually less than 10 for small numbers. Note also that this algorithm fails for `n = 0.0`.

Here is a slightly more elaborate method, using the floating point break up and combine functions `double frexp(double value, int *exp);` and `double ldexp(double x, int exp);`.  These functions do not perform any calculation but allow for a much better starting point, achieving completion in 4 or 5 iterations for most values:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    double n, x;
    int i, exp;

    printf("Enter a number:");
    while (scanf("%lf", &n) == 1 && n >= 0.0) {

        if (n == 0) {
            x = 0.0;
            i = 0;
        } else {
            frexp(n, &exp);
            x = ldexp(1.0, exp / 2);

            for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
                double new_guess = (x + (n / x)) / 2.0;
                if (new_guess == x)
                    break;
                x = new_guess;
            }
        }
        printf("%g: %.17g, %d iterations, diff=%.17g\n",
               n, x, i, sqrt(n) - x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```